# Ternary Operators as short conditional statements

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Is there anything wrong with using ternary operators in place of longer conditional statements in Javascript, for instance using:

```
(variable == "dog") ? dog_stuff() : false;
```

Rather than

```
if ( variable == "dog" ) 
{
    dog_stuff();
}
```

This may sound like a stupid question but I just find it's pretty quick and easy to read, I just don't want to be using it if there's a possible drawback?

Comment: there is noting wrong with using ternary operators

Comment: @Michael, the operand left of the `?` is the conditional, and you don't pass anything back to it. The whole structure `a ? b : c` is an expression. It looks odd in this case because it is being evaluated for its side effects, and its return value is being discarded.

Comment: @IanClelland Yeah my comment makes no sense, as my eyes were seeing the  `(variable == "dog")` as somehow being left of `=`.  Deleteing shortly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also write

```
(variable == 'dog') && dog_stuff();
```

if you don't have an else statement.

A few lines from backbone.js:

```
  options || (options = {});
  models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
  model = this.getByCid(models[i]) || this.get(models[i]);
```

You can group multiple statements, if it's very necessary:

```
(1==1) && (a=2,b=3)
alert(a); // 2
alert(b); // 3
```

Comment: Looks awkward, but a neat way to couple functionality

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for

Comment: I gave it +1 for cleverness, but honestly no one should do this. The efficiency, IMO, is not worth the down step on readability.

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong because you're telling your code to execute `false`. Imagine the following code:

```
if ( variable == "dog" ) 
{
    dog_stuff();
} else {
    false;
}
```

IMO the 4 line conditional function call is perfectly fine. You can shorthand it to:

```
if (variable == "dog") dog_stuff();
```

The only problem with this is if you comment it out, or add 1 more function then things look correct, but don't execute correctly:

```
if (variable == "dog") dog_walk(); dog_bark(); // dog_bark executes always!
if (variable == "dog") // dog_walk();
earn_cash(); // suddenly earn_cash() is dog-dependent.
```

Comment: I've always been wary of shortening the conditional statement because of this but I feel like using ternary operators make it fairly clear and removes the worry about uncertain dependencies.

Comment: I usually put braces inline: `if (condition) { execute(); }`

Answer (score 1):

As long as the format is easily understood by you and anyone else that may need to read the code, it's fine.

Comment: +1 on this.   It might be 10 characters shorter, but its better to write clear and concise code over something thats overly clever.